# Laravel Seeder class not found when I call it via DatabaseSeeder

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I made base upon [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) a Database migration named `class GridWithRoverSeeder` in `./database/seeds/GridWithRoverSeeder.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GridWithRoverSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('grid')->insert([
            'id' => 1,
            'width' => 10,
            'height' => 10,
        ]);

        DB::table('rover')->insert([
            'id' => 1,
            'rover_id' => 1,
            'command' => "RRMRMMRM",
            'last_command'=>""
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I call it from `DatabaseSeeder`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            GridWithRoverSeeder::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

But when I run `php artisan db:seed` I get the following error:

```
   ReflectionException  : Class GridWithRoverSeeder does not exist
```

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem and this helped fix it.

Delete your seeder file and regenerate it.

```
php artisan make:seed GridWithRoverSeeder
```

Run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Call the seeder in DatabaseSeeder

```
$this->call([
        GridWithRoverSeeder::class
    ]);
```

**Note:**
Avoid renaming the file manually.

Comment: What's different here from my answer?

Comment: Did you identified the caused? @shahburhan

Comment: Not a good approach to stolen the answer of other person  and just paste after some unnecessary modifications

Comment: We are all here to help. Doesn't matter which answer is selected as long as it actually solves the problem. If autoload dump alone would have solved the problem he would have selected your answer already even before I posted another solution. Peace.

Comment: I appreciate it if having some different approach! I'm not about the ans selected. But what you have learnt /perposed new here?

Comment: The file deletion is unessesary.

Comment: He had done everything correct. The only reason i thought to be the issue is he possibly renamed the file without renaming the class. And that's how he got it to fix. That's why I asked him to re generate the file. Even autoload dump isnt neccessary all the time. I don't know what all the fuss is about. He got it to work with this solution. autoload-dump alone didnt fix his problem

Comment: Yes... the file deletion was not required... only the single command `composer dump-autoload` should fix the issue... it's left user in dark without know the actual reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have run `composer dump-autoload` after creating seeder or any new class in laravel.